# Dialogflow - how to enable the agent to understand locations in training phrases?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm building a Dialogflow application which heavily depends on the location given by the user which may/may not be the current location of the user. So, I want to ignore the current location and go with location spelt by the user.

At the moment, I'm listing all the locations in one city, Dialogflow agent picks it up and determines the sub-domain area.

```
"location": {
    "subadmin-area": "Chicago"
  }
```

However,it'll be difficult to add each location as we expand the service to new areas.

Is there anyway for the agent to self learn the locations on a given area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won’t self-learn this.  What I would do is find a database or some other locations dataset and write a script that uses the Dialogflow API to programmatically generate *entities* with location names.

Or better yet, use the system-provided entities that Google has already created.  See the Geography section at https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities

Comment: This helps. Thanks!